# Why doesn't my file move into "en.lproj" but instead into a new "English.lproj" after "Make file Localizable" in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, localization

This is a bit confusing:

First I used genstrings, which created me a Localizable.strings file inside an **en.lproj** folder (also exists on the file system like that).

Then I had a JSON file which I wanted to localize, so I opened the info-pane for that file and choose "Make File Localizable". Xcode then created an **English.lproj** folder on the file system and also a group called like this. It then moved my file into there.

So now I ended up having **en.lproj** and **English.lproj** for basically the same thing: English stuff.

I'm not happy with this situation. Can / should I do anything about it? How can I fix that?

Also, can someone point out what's the difference between using "English.lproj" vs. "en.lproj"? I bet there *is* a difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's an Xcode bug. Just move everything in the `English.lproj` folder to `en.lproj` folder. I haven't checked with Xcode 4.1, but previous versions of Xcode wouldn't allow you to add new localizations if you delete the `English.lproj` folder, so don't delete it.

You could manually edit your project file to avoid the problem [as this post suggest](http://eschatologist.net/blog/?p=224), but I've never really found doing so to be worth it.

Some background -- prior to Max OS X 10.4 the legacy (but more user-readable) names such as “English”, “Spanish”, etc., were used,  but the [Apple internationalization documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LanguageDesignations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002144-130435) states that these values are now deprecated:

> In addition to the ISO language designators, the bundle routines
>   also recognize several legacy language designators. These designators
>   let you specify a language by a user-readable name, instead of by a
>   two or three character code. Designators included names such as
>   English, French, German, Japanese, Chinese, Spanish, Italian, Swedish,
>   and Portuguese among others. **Although these names are still recognized
>   and processed by the NSBundle class and Core Foundation bundle
>   functions, their use is deprecated and support for them in future
>   versions of Mac OS X or iPhone OS is not guaranteed**. Use the codes
>   described in “Language Designations” and “Regional Designations”
>   instead.

Answer (score 2):

You should use ISO-639-1 (two-letter) or ISO-639-2 (three-letter) language codes codes for localization purposes of all languages other than English. XCode still uses “English” instead of “en” as their default localization.

See http://eschatologist.net/blog/?p=224 for info.